# Is it possible to create a non modal non-cancellable job in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to create a progress monitor in eclipse which is non modal and non cancelable.
Is it possible to do so in eclipse?

Comment: Are you asking about `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` and the `IProgressMonitor` that get passed to its `run` method?

Answer (score 0):

The Progress Monitor does not actually control those two things. The UI is responsible for whether the running code is modal and that code is responsible for checking and reacting to whether the progress monitor has been cancelled--it might just ignore it.